# Linux send unicode character to active application

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Ok, so I'm trying to develop an app using C++ and Qt4 for Linux that will map certain key sequences to special Unicode characters. Also, I'm trying to make it bilingual, so the special Unicode character sent depends on the selected language. Example: AltGr+s will send ß or ș, depending whether German or Romanian is selected. On Windows, I have achieved this using AutoHotKey. However, I couldn't get IronAHK to work on Linux so I have written myself a nice Qt Application for it, using Qxt to register "global" shortcuts. I have tried this snippet:

```
void mainWnd::sendKeypress( unsigned int keycode )
{
    Display *display = QX11Info::display();
    Window curr_focus;
    int revert_to;

    XGetInputFocus( display, &curr_focus, &revert_to );

    XTestFakeKeyEvent( display, keycode, true,  0 );
    XTestFakeKeyEvent( display, keycode, false, 1 );

    XFlush( display );
}
```

copied from another application(where it works), but here it seems to do nothing. Also, there might be a problem with the fact that the characters I'm trying to send aren't found on a US 101 Keyboard, that I currently use on my laptop(and as the layout in the OS).

So my question is: how do I make the app send a Unicode character to whichever app has focus, inserting a special character(sort of like KCharMap)? Remember, these are special characters which are not found on a normal US Keyboard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aboid using X11 API directly under Qt. Use only the low-level Qt API

Comment: Seems you are trying write an IME, this is a well sort out matter in any OS, you can use any platform for doing input methods under Linux(i.e. m17n lib)